# SQL Server: Table-value UDF with table-value parameter from inside view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2017

I'm building a database-contained unit-testing framework.
The details aren't important, but this premise has led me into some unusual situations.

Right now, I'm trying to create a view for some specific unit test data, and I'm trying to:
`CREATE VIEW [foo] AS SELECT * FROM TableValueUDF ( TableValueParam )`
(Side note: moving the UDF logic into the view itself, would result in huge amounts of code duplication across dozens of database objects, if not hundreds - which is why I'm avoiding it.)

The obvious problem here is, you can't pass a variable into the view.
But the unit test data is technically static ... so I reverted to:
`CREATE VIEW [foo] AS SELECT * FROM TableValueUDF ( ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES ... ) ) )`
... where the end-user-developer can manually define their desired unit tests, for every test view.

And of course SQL server is very unhappy with this. *(Error messages indicated in code below.)*
But I've never encountered this scenario before, and I have no idea how to rearrange this query to accomplish what I'm trying to do.
(Is this a situation where `CROSS APPLY` would be helpful? I don't really understand cross apply.)

My actual code is much larger and more complex than this, so I've been testing with a simple example scenario to help isolate the problem in repro.

Naturally, the error messages don't make any sense. *(Indicated inside the code where they appear)*
And Googling these error messages yields completely different situations, unhelpful here.

Example UDT and UDF definitions:

```
/* Table-value UDT */
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntNameList]
AS TABLE
(
    [Value]    INT             NOT NULL ,
    [NameText] NVARCHAR ( 48 ) NOT NULL
)

GO

/* Table-value UDF with table-value parameter */
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ProcessData]
(
    @tableValueParam [IntNameList] READONLY
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    SELECT
        [Value]    ,
        [NameText] ,

        /* Simple example calculation: Is [Value] odd or even? */
        CAST ( IIF ( [Value] % 2 <> 0 , 1 , 0 ) AS BIT )
     AS [ValueOdd]

    FROM @tableValueParam
)

GO
```

Testing with a declared variable, to ensure UDF operates as expected:

```
DECLARE @param [IntNameList]

INSERT INTO @param VALUES

    ( /* Value    */ 110 ,
      /* NameText */ N'Steve'
    ) ,

    ( /* Value    */ 111 ,
      /* NameText */ N'Mason'
    ) ,

    ( /* Value    */ 112 ,
      /* NameText */ N'Kimberly'
    )

/* Works as expected */
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ProcessData] ( @param )

GO
```

[image]

Testing with `CREATE VIEW`, which is the actual scenario I'm trying to achieve:

```
/*  Errors:

    1) "Only one expression can be specified in the select list
            when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

    2) "Operand type clash: int is incompatible with IntNameList"
*/

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ProcessExampleData] AS

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ProcessData] ( ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES

        ( /* Value    */ 110 ,
          /* NameText */ N'Steve'
        ) ,

        ( /* Value    */ 111 ,
          /* NameText */ N'Mason'
        ) ,

        ( /* Value    */ 112 ,
          /* NameText */ N'Kimberly'
        )

    ) AS [ExampleData] ( [Value]    ,
                         [NameText] ) ) )
```

Comment: Does it have to be a view? Can you embed the function in a procedure?

Comment: @Xedni Sure. That would add yet another database object for each test batch, but if that's the price I have to pay, I guess I can handle that.

Comment: Adding a view is yet another database object though as well. If you can bake the test logic into a procedure, you can pass in whatever you want and have it routed to the function if you mainly want to avoid having to copy/paste object definitions

Comment: @Xedni Right, it's ... a little more complicated than that, in reality. But I like where you're going with this. I'm warming up to the idea. I'd still be very interested to see if SQL Server has some obscure syntax that would make this view work. Otherwise, I'll convert to a procedure as plan b.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. Typically when you need a "parameterized view", you'd typically use a table-valued function, like you have. But since (i'm assuming) your test framework can't simply invoke that directly, the only way to get your test data in is via a stored procedure, or dynamic/prepared SQL.

Comment: This is no OOP, such encapsulation kills sql.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Fair enough. Thankfully this is purely a testing apparatus, not production.

Comment: `moving the UDF logic into the view itself, would result in huge amounts of code ` can you give more details? Why is it a `view` at all? Your sample code represents the problem you're facing with this specific approach but gives no hints on your general intent.